# Macbook Pro start up is stuck

Tags: macbook-pro, startup

I have a Macbook Pro. I think it's a 2013 but I'm not sure.
All of the sudden when I turn it on I can hear the start up chime, but the screen remains dark. After a long time, sometimes, the display seems to turn on, but nothing appear on the screen and it remains dark.
I tried starting up with Command + R and Command + V but nothing worked.

Any ideas?

Comment: I would bet that you backlight has died.  If it has the logo that lights up, try shing a flashlight through it to see if anything shows up on the screen.  You can also try shining a light at an angle to the screen. Finally, try plugging in an external monitor.

Comment: There are many possible causes for this, especially on an old computer. My gut tells me it's hardware related (most likely a faulty logic board or drive, but could be the screen etc). You could try connecting to an external screen to see if that makes a difference and if not booting up from an external disk to see if that option works. If so, that identifies the cause easily enough.

Comment: Can you connect an external display, and see if that works?

Comment: Hey guys. Thanks a lot for the help. I actually left it overnight and tried again in the morning and the machine managed to start up on my first attempt. I have no idea how the issue resolved. But it just did. I then updated the OS and it's now working fine. It happened in the past that other machines would take a while to start up, but this time I just tried several times and thought there was a bigger issue. Seems like not though. Sorry the late reply. Was away for Xmas celebrations